# Pandas pandas.to_datetime(), incorrect parsing

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe `df` with lists the Year, Month, and Day separately, with all days of the year. The following is a sample for December:

```
Year    Month    Day
1995     12      14
1995     12      15
1995     12      15
1995     12      16
1995     12      17
```

And I wanted to create a timestamp with this data. So, I try this:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Year*10000 + df.Month*100 + df.Day, format="%Y%M%d")
```

Unfortunately, all of the months are listed as January. The following is outputted as this:

```
1995-01-14 00:01:00
1995-01-15 00:01:00
1995-01-15 00:01:00
1995-01-16 00:01:00
1995-01-17 00:01:00
```

What is my error above?

Comment: what are the dtypes here? are they numeric or str?

Comment: You should be able to do `pd.to_dateimte(df.astype(str).sum(axis=1), format='%Y%m%d')` if you need to convert to str

Comment: Isn't your format string wrong? shouldn't it be `"%Y%m%d"`?

Comment: @EdChum My format string was wrong. It should be `%Y%m%d`

Comment: so does that fix the issue?

Comment: @EdChum Yes, I'm a fool. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string is wrong:

```
"%Y%M%d"
```

`%M` means minutes which is why your month defaulted to `1` and you have minutes in your datetimes.

Use:

```
"%Y%m%d"
```

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for the correct format specifiers